# Nativescript 6 updated broke styles

Tags: nativescript

I just updated to Nativescript 6 and it seems a lot of my stylings are now funky. Is there a breaking changes list somewhere? Here are some examples:

- On iOS my "Back" buttons went from white to dark
- in Android all nested FlexboxLayout are now not lining up
- some images that were in FlexboxLayout and set by height="20" stretch="aspectFit" fill the whole container, ect.

Code Example:

```
<FlexboxLayout
        flexDirection="row"
        class="title-bar"
        alignContent="center"
        justifyContent="space-between"
        ref="view"
    >
        <Label :text="title" class="title-bar-label" />

        <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row">
            <Image
                src="res://share"
                stretch="aspectFit"
                width="25"
                height="30"
                marginRight="20"
                v-if="share"
                @tap="$emit('share')"

            />

            <Image src="res://title_logo" stretch="aspectFit" width="30"  />
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </FlexboxLayout>
```

Comment: Did you upgrade {N} theme too? It has got [breaking changes listed here](https://github.com/NativeScript/theme#breaking-changes).

Comment: Yes I updated that and changed my scss file to import the core, I used the "Dark" theme before so I think thats all i needed. Overall there app looks similar so maybe there is just some bugs with Flexbox? Seems all the elements that are wonky have FlexboxLayout as the parent?

Comment: I can't comment on that unless you share any sample code to confirm the issue.

Comment: I just added an example of a nested flexbox layout. Work in iOS but in Android it just the child Flexbox to a new line

Comment: I don't see any issue, the flexbox just appear on same line. Please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.